# How to get value of a child based on the text of another child within the same JavaScript parent

Tags: javascript, html, css, cypress

so I want to be able to get "Text B" from the table below using Cypress but have tried many things and I can only get "Party B".

```
<div class="table">
  <div class="label">
    <span class="labelText">Party A</span>
  </div>
  <div class="text">Text A</div>
</div>

<div class="table">
  <div class="label">
    <span class="labelText">Party B</span>
  </div>
  <div class="text">Text B</div>
</div>
```

I have been using cy.get(`div[class="table"]`).contains(`div[class="label"]`, "Party B").click() to click on the text for "Party B", but don't know how to click on the other child of the same parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the table containing "Party B", specify the selector inside `.contains()`

```js
cy.contains('div.table', 'Party B')  // returns the table with "Party B" inside somewhere 
  .find('div.text')                  // find the 2nd child which has class "text"
  .click()
```

There are variations you could use, if you know "Text B" is the actual text

```js
cy.contains('div.text', 'Text B')
  .click()
```

If you want to navigate first to `div[class="table"]`, then to `div[class="label"]`

```js
cy.contains('Party B')               // returns the <span> owning "Party B" 
  .click()
  .parent('div.label')               // go up to div[class="label"]
  .sibling('div.text')               // go to next element at that level
  .click()
```

Be careful about doing multiple clicks in a chain, usually they have side-effects.

It's better to start a new chain after each click.